# Strongloop Oracle connecting via script

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, oracle11g, loopbackjs

I'm currently testing [Loopback](http://loopback.io/) and using the [Arc](http://strongloop.com/node-js/arc/) interface.

I can connect to my oracle database and create models from the tables all served up in explorer. (all good).

but now I seem to be struggling when wanting to write some custom code and call an oracle procedure. I am unable to connect due to the oracle module not being found. (Arc works and I have all the correct packages installed)

I'm trying to connect to oracle for custom route but keep getting 'Cannot find module 'oracle''.

Code Example to try and connect is as follows;

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/oracletest', function(req, res) {

    var settings = {};
    var oracle = require("oracle")(settings);

    var connectData = { "user": "userhere", "password": "passwordhere", "tns": "tnshere" };

    oracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {
      console.log('must have connected woooohoooo');
      connection.close(); // call this when you are done with the connection 
    });
}
```

This is following the guide from [strong-oracle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-oracle) which is a dependancy installed with the loopback-oracle-connector.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for catching the typo. The module name should be strong-oracle. Please use:

```
var oracle = require("strong-oracle")(settings);
```

I just fixed the README at https://github.com/strongloop/strong-oracle.

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for reply. 

I altered the code to say strong-oracle but it still doesn't seem to find the module. I get the following when visiting explorer window for the custom route.

>
    Loopback
    500 Error: Cannot find module 'strong-oracle'
       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
       at require (module.js:380:17)

I even initially tried using require('loopback-oracle-connector') but at least now I know it should be 'strong-oracle'.